# Array of objects in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, javascript-objects

I'm new to learning Javascript. at this stage, I want to use/decalre/initialize an array of objects.

Here is my code to initialise an object :

```
function player(name){
    this.name = name;

    this.getName = function(){
        alert(this.name);
    }
}
```

and here is where I need to use the array of players(objects)

```
function hallOfFame(nbrPlayers){
    var arrayOfPlayers = [] 

}
```

Can anyone help me please how to create this array of objects. Thank you in advance :)

Comment: What is `nbrPlayers`?

Comment: Can I show you some easier way to create array of objects? (:

Comment: `var arrayOfPlayers = [ new player('Elitia'), new player('Mike') ];` See [MDN's documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) for more examples.

Comment: @JustinTaddei : nbrPlayers means the number of objects that I want to use to build my array with. I want to create an array like this in C, arrayOfPlayers[nbrPlayers]

Comment: arrays don't work like that in javascript they don't come with a size

Comment: @Kinduser, yes please :)

Comment: @NoahReinagel, how array don't come with size, while we use this syntaxe : var myArray = new Array[10];

Comment: @ElitiaCandy Give me a minute.

Comment: You can initialize an array with an index, but you don't have to do that in js, their size is not fixed as in C or other languages

Comment: you don't need to specify the array size in javascript, and you probably want to return new objects in your `player` function.

Comment: @ElitiaCandy We *don't* use that syntax, at least not in Javascript.

Comment: @ElitiaCandy `var myArray = new Array[10];` is not valid javascript.

Comment: @baao, thank you for you comment. So my code needs only to be something like : var arrayOfPlayers = [new Player()] ??? 
What if I want an array of 10 players for example ??

Comment: Doesn't matter. Please have a look at my answer, maybe that explains it already

Comment: @Bergi : Ok thank you. I tought it was a correct syntax

Comment: @JohanP : Ok thank you. I tought it was a correct syntax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like the following to create an array of players when instantiating a new HallOfFame. The `addPlayer` prototype will let you, well, add new players to the array later. In general - you don't need to specify a fixed length for an array in javascript. The size is flexible, so you can just create an empty array to have an array of players, then push onto that.

```js
function Player(name){
    this.name = name;

    this.getName = function(){
        alert(this.name);
    }
}

function HallOfFame(players) {
  this.players = Array.from(players);
}

HallOfFame.prototype.addPlayer = function(player) {
 this.players = this.players.concat(player);
}


let p1 = new Player("foo");
let p2 = new Player("bar");
let p3 = new Player("baz");

let hOf = new HallOfFame([p1,p2]); // instantiate HallOfFame and add two players

hOf.addPlayer(p3); // add another player

console.log(hOf); // will show you an HallOfFame object holding 3 players
```

Comment: @baao, what a community here in stackoverflow. Thank you thank you soooo much for your help and your time. That fits my requirements and helps me to understand a lot about JS more than any tutorial or course. God bless you

Comment: In ES6, I'd recommend to use `Array.from(players)` to make the copy instead of `[].concat`

Comment: Thanks @Bergi that makes it obvious easier!

Comment: Not necessarily easier, but definitely more obvious :D

Answer (score 2):

```
function createPlayerArray(number) {
  var players = [];
  for (i = 0; i < number; i++) {
    players.push(new Player("No Name"));
  }
  return players;
}
```

this will create an array of players

Answer (score 1):

Just for learning purposes, tell me if it's too easy, I will delete it.

```js
var dogs = ['Gustavo', 'Heisen', 'Berg', 'Jessie'],
    race = ['Labrador', 'Doberman', 'Spaniel', 'Husky'],
    result = [];
    
    dogs.forEach(function(v,i){ //iterate over each element from dogs array
      var obj = {}; //create an empty object to store our data
      obj[v] = race[i]; //assign a key (which is name of the dog) and it's value (his race) to obj
      result.push(obj); //push object into the result array
    });                 //repeat! (:
    
    console.log(result); //show our array of objects!
```

Comment: That is so helpful. Thank you @Kind user :)

Answer (score 1):

As you're using the `player` function to create objects, it seems like a good use case for a [`class`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes) declaration, which stated purpose is to "provide a much simpler and clearer syntax to create objects":

```
class Player {
    constructor(name) {
        function capitalizeName(fullName) {
          return fullName
          .split(' ')
          .map((s) => {
            return `${s.charAt(0).toUpperCase()}${s.slice(1).toLowerCase()}`
          })
          .join(' ')
        }
        this.name = capitalizeName(name)
    }

    getName () {
      return this.name
    }

    alertName () {
      alert(this.getName())
    }
}
```

You can then use the [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method create an array of `Player`s from an array of strings, like this:

```
function hallOfFame(playerNames) {
  return playerNames.map((playerName) => new Player(playerName))
}
```

You can test the function using the [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) method:

```
> let myPlayerNames = ['ADA', 'bob', 'CaRlA', 'DenniS', 'ElITIa']
> let myHallOfFame = hallOfFame(myPlayerNames)
> myHallOfFame.forEach((player) => player.alertName())
```

Comment: Thank you so much. that's a new concept and it's very helpful to me

Comment: @ElitiaCandy no problem. I updated the `capitalizeName` function to handle full names. I believe that, eventually, you will also want to learn about [functional programming](http://eloquentjavascript.net/05_higher_order.html) and [immutability](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/), which are important concepts also present in this answer.

Comment: I will take a look on those links. That is so kind of you. Thank you so much @Marcus

Answer (score 1):

```
//making array of books
var books = [];
    var new_book = {id: "book1", name: "twilight", category: "Movies", price: 10};
    books.push(new_book);
    new_book = {id: "book2", name: "The_call", category: "Movies", price: 17};
    books.push(new_book);
    console.log(books[0].id);
    console.log(books[0].name);
    console.log(books[0].category);
    console.log(books[0].price);

// also we have array of albums
var albums = []    
    var new_album = {id: "album1", name: "Ahla w Ahla", category: "Music", price: 15};
    albums.push(new_album);
    new_album = {id: "album2", name: "El-leila", category: "Music", price: 29};
    albums.push(new_album);
//Now, content[0] contains all books & content[1] contains all albums
var content = [];
content.push(books);
content.push(albums);
var my_books = content[0];
var my_albums = content[1];
console.log(my_books[0].name);
console.log(my_books[1].name); 

console.log(my_albums[0].name);
console.log(my_albums[1].name);
```

This Example Works with me:
[Expected output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zWvt9.png)